# download a csv file using a https request with R

Tags: r, csv, https

I would like to download a csv file using a https request.
Using a web browser, I can download this [file](https://indices.euronext.com/nyx_eu_listings/price_chart/download_historical?typefile=csv&layout=vertical&typedate=dmy&separator=point&mic=XPAR&isin=FR0003500008&name=CAC%2040&namefile=Price_Data_Historical&from=0&to=1426550400000&adjusted=1&base=0).

I would like to do it in R. 
I did try to use the getURL function from RCurl package without success.

```
library(RCurl) URL <-
     "https://indices.euronext.com/nyx_eu_listings/price_chart/download_historical?typefile=csv&layout=vertical&typedate=dmy&separator=point&mic=XPAR&isin=FR0003500008&name=CAC%2040&namefile=Price_Data_Historical&from=0&to=1426550400000&adjusted=1&base=0"

csvfile <- getURL(URL)
```

tks for your help

Comment: What error if any do you get from the `https` call to `getURL()`?  This sounds like there may be an `SSH` problem at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

Use download.file then read.table instead of getURL:

```
URL <- "https://indices.euronext.com/nyx_eu_listings/price_chart/download_historical?typefile=csv&layout=vertical&typedate=dmy&separator=point&mic=XPAR&isin=FR0003500008&name=CAC%2040&namefile=Price_Data_Historical&from=0&to=1426550400000&adjusted=1&base=0"
        download.file(URL, "name.txt")
        data.url <- read.table("name.txt", skip= 3, sep=",", header=TRUE)
```

You neep to skip reading the fist 3 rows. But then if you need that metadata information:

> metadata <- read.table("name.txt", nrow=3)

Comment: it doesn't work with download.file ! the error message is "URL not supported".

Comment: download.file( "https://indices.euronext.com/nyx_eu_listings/price_chart/download_historical?typefile=csv&layout=vertical&typedate=dmy&separator=point&mic=XPAR&isin=FR0003500008&name=CAC%2040&namefile=Price_Data_Historical&from=0&to=1426550400000&adjusted=1&base=0", "name.txt")

Comment: Or call the link "Link". Perhaps you have a function name conflit with URL.